# Exceed Maximum Length SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, sqldatatypes

I am trying to insert values from other table.

```
TABLE A
SOURCE_NAME VARCHAR2(1500 BYTE)
to
TABLE B
PAYMENT_SOURCE_DESCRIPTION VARCHAR2(1500 BYTE)
```

BUT I AM GETTING THIS ERROR

> Rejected - Error on table "APP1"."TABLE_B", column PAYMENT_SOURCE_DESCRIPTION.
>   Field in data file exceeds maximum length

trim(TABLA_A.source_name)  AS "Payment Source Description"

Comment: In the error message you have PAYMENT_SOURCE_DESCRIPTION, but above is PAYMENT_SOURCE. Are you sure that it is the same column?

Comment: Hi edited, type error

Comment: could you check if `source_Name` is 1500 Byte and not 1500 char? try to dump a value auf SOURCE_NAME

Answer (score 0):

The error code looks like SQLLOADER. This has(had?) a default length of 255, so stating

PAYMENT_SOURCE_DESCRIPTION char(1500)

in the control file could possibly help. I'd have put this into a comment, but I'm new and cannot comment at the moment.